# Can't listen to port 4445; sqlite3

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, asterisk, sqlite, freepbx

So I have a dedicated machine running Ubuntu 12.04 server with FreePBX 2.9. Earlier I was attempting to familiarize myself with SQL via sqlite3, but I received this dreaded error:

```
SQLite header and source version mismatch
```

So I saw a possible fix was to remove sqlite3 from the system and re-install. I did, and I went to reload FreePBX via:

```
$ amportal restart
```

And now it's giving me this recurring error:

```
Can't listen to port 4445
```

It repeats every 5 or so seconds unless I log out and log back in.

Anyway, my question is this: is there anything I can do to fix this? I tried re-installing sqlite3, but I'm not screwing with anything until I get the machine back like it was. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This was the print-out from an lsof command:

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
perl    6773 asterisk    4u  IPv4 560096      0t0  TCP *:4445 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: What have you got on port 4445, then? My FreePBX system has nothing using that port.

Comment: @MichaelHampton post edited above.